# Color at specific point - ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to color at a specific point of the screen using ncurses lib.
I have written this code:

```
#include<curses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    move(10, 10);
    printw(" \n");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

There is a better way to do this? Or this is the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [`mvchgat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mvchgat) for changing the color (and other attributes) of an already-existing character.
You can also use [`mvaddch`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mvaddch)`(10, 10, ' ' | COLOR_PAIR(1))` to move the cursor and output a space character with a custom color (or other attributes).